# Displaying MySQL data with PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

With help from some of you guys, I managed to partially get the functionality I wanted. Now I'm stuck again, and I'd need some more help.

Check the live version [here](http://www.rujzgalvanic.tk/playground), the code is below. What I need is:

-
Figure out how to switch to the next/previous product on **both** sides of the screen with a single click of the arrows. The left side works as expected, the right one doesn't switch in any case.

-
Make the results of slika1, slika2 and slika3 (they contain the filenames of three separate images) on the right side display as links that will switch the image on the left side.

-
Modify the code to prevent SQL injection attacks (optional at the moment, but it would be welcome)

I'm pretty sure the whole functionality could be contained in a single file to be called with POST, but I'm really not sure how to do it properly. That would be a bonus too!

Here's my code:

HTML (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.post( "art.php", { pic: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#picture").html( data );
     });
     $.post( "info.php", { id: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#info").html( data );
     });

     $("#picture").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
           var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $("#picture").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
           $.post( "art.php", { pic: picture_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#picture").html( data );
           });
           return false;
     });

          $("#info").on("click",".get_info", function(e){
           var info_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $("#info").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
           $.post( "info.php", { pic: info_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#info").html( data );
           });
           return false;
     });
});
</script>
<title>2199</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container"> <img src="logo.png" class="boxy"> </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron special">
  <div id="picture" align="center"> </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron special2">
  <div id="info" align="center"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML (art.php):

```
$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = '2199'; //databasename

//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["pic"]) && is_numeric($_POST["pic"]))
{
    $current_picture = filter_var($_POST["pic"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_picture=1;
}

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){   
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id > $current_picture ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $next_id = $result->id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id < $current_picture ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $prev_id = $result->id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT artikel, slika1 FROM gola WHERE id = $current_picture LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result){

    //construct next/previous button
    $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_pic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left rujz"></span></a>':'';
    $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_pic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right rujz"></span></a>':'';

    //output html

    echo '<div class="prod_img" style="background-image: url(pictures/';
    echo $result->slika1;
    echo '); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;">';
    echo '<h3>';
    echo $prev_button; 
    echo $result->artikel;
    echo $next_button;
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

HTML (info.php):

```
<?php

$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = '2199'; //databasename

//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["info"]) && is_numeric($_POST["info"]))
{
    $current_info = filter_var($_POST["info"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_info=1;
}

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){   
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id > $current_info ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result2){
    $next_id = $result2->id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id < $current_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result2){
    $prev_id = $result2->id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT artikel, slika1, slika2, slika3, dim1, dim2, dim3, obdelava, dodatno FROM gola WHERE id = $current_info LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result2){

    //construct next/previous button
    $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left rujz-wht"></span></a>':'';
    $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right rujz-wht"></span></a>':'';

    //output html

    echo '<div class="info">';
    echo '<h3 style="color: #fff !important;">';
    echo $prev_button; 
    echo $result2->artikel;
    echo $next_button;
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<p>';
    echo $result2->slika1;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->slika2;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->slika3;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dim1;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dim2;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dim3;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->obdelava;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dodatno;
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
.special, .special .jumbotron {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.special2, .special2 .jumbotron {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #62a70f;
    border: 0.5rem solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.logo {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 10%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#picture {
    border: 0px red solid;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.prod_img {
    height: 100%;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: #62a70f;
}
.boxy {
    border: 0.5rem solid white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2.5%;
    right: 5%;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1rem;
    /*  height: 30rem;*/
    background-color: rgba(64,64,64,1);
    border-radius: 3rem;/*  background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
.boxy {
    border: 0.5rem solid white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    /*  height: 30rem;*/
    background-color: rgba(64,64,64,1);
    border-radius: 3rem;/*  background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
.navbar {
    min-height: 10% !important;
    max-height: 10% !important;
    height: 10%;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0px solid green;
    background-color: #0e0e0e;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.navbar-header {
    border: 0px solid green;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.logo {
    visibility: collapse;
}
.special, .special .jumbotron {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.special2, .special2 .jumbotron {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-size: 4.8rem;
}
.rujz {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: #62a70f;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

.rujz-wht {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

}
 @keyframes example {
 0% {
bottom:-10%;
}
 100% {
bottom:0%;
}
}
```

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to shorten the code you display here to the bare minimum showing the problem. In this case, no need for SQL queries (use hardcoded demo data instead), less CSS, etc.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm (obviously) a noob and I'm afraid of shortening the code as I don't want to remove anything that could be important to someone trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using the carousel in bootstrap, since it's much better than what you are trying to achieve using Javascript.

Also, your MySQL queries can be shortened and changed into a more efficient code, by using a whileloop to output in to different sections.

But to not complicate things, 
I assume that you are trying to get 2 different sections, one with a image and another with infomation? If so, you would want to cycle between 2 same slideshow with the same function. To do this,

```
<div id="Section1">Description</div> 
<div id="Section1">slika1</div>
<div id="Shift">    Next </div>
```

and having a seperate javascript to cycle through each section

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Section1").cycle();

$("#shift").click(function () { 
    $("#Section1").cycle('next');
});
});
```

a live example could be viewed here : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html

edit: i wrote this entire answer without understanding your code.. so.. further clarifications could help :)